# failed to recall onDraw method in View

Tags: android, multithreading, canvas

i wanna make something like puzzle(put images together) in my onDraw() method in custom view. so at first i call it and display my whole puzzle as well.
but after a time i wanna change my puzzle images. so when i change the source of images from another thread and invalidate(),but may app will be forced close.
from your perspective what should i do to reach this goal??
here is my code:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawARGB(100, 255, 255, 0);
    canvas.translate(posX, posY);
    canvas.scale(imageScale,imageScale);
        InitDrawing(canvas);

}

 public void InitDrawing(Canvas canvas)
{
    for (int a = 0 ; a < 5 ;a++)
    {
        for(int i =0 ; i<4 ; i++)
        {
            canvas.drawBitmap(toop,(toop.getWidth()*i )  ,(toop.getHeight()*a) , null);
            downloading  = true;
            IMGnotExisting = true;
            Log.i("Canvas loop", "Showing");

        }   
    }
}


public class SDChecker  implements Runnable
{
    public SDChecker()
    {
//          String name = s;
        PauseTHR = new Object();
        pause = false;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
//          while( true)
//          {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/GreatMap","tile0.jpg");
            if (file.exists())
            {
                toop = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/GreatMap/tile0.jpg");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                invalidate();
                Log.i("Create      bit           map", "Bitmap    create");
//                  Toast.makeText(getContext(), "loadmap tile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                IMGnotExisting = false;

            }
            else
            {
                IMGnotExisting = true;
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

call invalidate only from the UI thread.
To call invalidate outside of the UI thread, use `postInvalidate()`.

Hope this helps.